# How do I recursively rename folders with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, recursion, file-rename

Recursive renaming files using PS is trivial (variation on example from [Mike Ormond's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/01/20/powershell-batch-rename.aspx)):

```
dir *_t*.gif -recurse 
    | foreach { move-item -literal $_ $_.Name.Replace("_thumb[1]", "")}
```

I'm trying to recursively rename a folder structure.

The use case is I'd like to be able to rename a whole VS.NET Solution (e.g. from Foo.Bar to Bar.Foo). To do this there are several steps:

1. Rename folders (e.g. \Foo.Bar\Foo.Bar.Model => \Bar.Foo\Bar.Foo.Model)
2. Rename files (e.g. Foo.Bar.Model.csproj => Bar.Foo.Model.csproj)
3. Find and Replace within files to correct for namespace changes (e.g. 'namespace Foo.Bar' => 'namespace Bar.Foo')

I'm currently working the first step in this process.

I found [this](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1169) posting, which talks about the challenges, and claims a solution but doesn't talk about what that solution is.

I keep running into the recursion wall. If I let PS deal with the recursion using a flag, the parent folder gets renamed before the children, and the script throws an error. If I try to implement the recursion myself, my head get's all achy and things go horribly wrong - for the life of me I cannot get things to start their renames at the tail of the recursion tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the solution rbellamy ended up with:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | %{$_.FullName} |
Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending |
% {
    Write-Host $_
    $Item = Get-Item $_
    $PathRoot = $Item.FullName | Split-Path
    $OldName = $Item.FullName | Split-Path -Leaf
    $NewName = $OldName -replace $OldText, $NewText
    $NewPath = $PathRoot | Join-Path -ChildPath $NewName
    if (!$Item.PSIsContainer -and $Extension -contains $Item.Extension) {
        (Get-Content $Item) | % {
            #Write-Host $_
            $_ -replace $OldText, $NewText
        } | Set-Content $Item
    }
    if ($OldName.Contains($OldText)) {
        Rename-Item -Path $Item.FullName -NewName $NewPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the -literalPath option on Get-Items will mean any symbols which appear in the path or filename will not be interpreted. Also ordering my length of the full name does not work in all cases. If you have folders of substantially different lengths and a lower path is renamed before higher one the script will report the file/folder is not able to be located. It's path would have changed.

Answer (score 3):

How about this - do a recursive list of the full names, sort it in descending order by the length of the full name,  and then run that back through your rename routine.

e.g.

```
gci <directory> -recurse |
 foreach {$_.fullname} |
  sort -length -desc
```

Comment: I like this. Works a treat after a little tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something in this is useful, here's a snippet that recurses and prepends "pre" to a directory structure

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem c:/foldertorecurse -rec |  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq 1} |  sort fullname -descending
foreach ( $dir in $dirs ) { rename-item -path $dir.fullname -newname ("pre" + $dir.name) }
```

Comment: You essentially have what @mjolinir had, but you have it sorting by the fullname, which doesn't properly place the sort in reverse order of location in hierarchy. Nice though, thanks!