# Add folder date to the foldername

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have a script which recursively modifies the "creation date" and the"modified date" of folders to match the oldest and newest files in folders (image files).

After that I want to add the creation date of each folder as a prefix to its name. I have written the code that creates the desired name but I don't know how to rename the folders.

```
$colFolder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "." |
             Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} |
             Sort-Object Fullname -Descending
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
foreach ($strFolder In $colFolder) {
  Trap [Exception] {
    Write-Verbose "TRAPPED:" 
    Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message;
    Write-Verbose $strFolder.FullName
    Continue
  }
  $Path = $strFolder.FullName
  $Folder = Get-Item $Path

  # Get Newest file in folder
  $strOldestTime = (Get-ChildItem $Path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1).LastWriteTime
  $strNewestTime = (Get-ChildItem $Path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last  1).LastWriteTime

  # Change the date to match the newest file if it doesn't already
  $Folder.CreationTime = $strOldestTime
  $Folder.LastWriteTime = $strNewestTime

  # add the date as the prefix of the folder (in which the files are)
  $date = $strOldestTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
  $foldername = $Folder.Name.split("\")[-1]
  Write-Verbose "$date- $foldername"

  #now rename the folder to above name
}
```

Comment: You say that you want to add the folder's *creation date* to the folder name, but your code says that you want to add the oldest *modification date* of the folder's *child items* to the folder name. Please clarify.

Comment: As a side note: PowerShell v2 and newer support `try`/`catch` for handling exceptions, so you shouldn't use `trap` anymore. If you're still using PowerShell v1 I *strongly* recommend to upgrade to at least PowerShell v2.

Comment: I had set that same date (the oldest modification date of the children) on the folder creation date a few lines earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming folders can be done as [@onupdatecascade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139938/onupdatecascade) described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518237/1630171).

```
Rename-Item -Path $Folder.FullName -NewName $newname
```

If you have at least PowerShell v3 (which I highly recommend) you can use the parameter `-LiteralPath` for the current folder path to avoid issues with special characters:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $Folder.FullName -NewName $newname
```

With that said, there are a couple improvements to your code I'd like to suggest.

- `Get-ChildItem -Recurse "."`:
  `Get-ChildItem` uses the current working directory by default, so `"."` can be omitted.
- `Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"}`:
  The objects you get from `Get-ChildItem` have a boolean property `IsContainer` that indicates whether you have a folder or not. No need to use a regex match on the mode. Also, in PowerShell v3 and newer you can omit this step entirely, because the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet has an additional parameter `-Directory` that lists only folders.
- Misused [hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (pt.1):

  ```
  foreach ($strFolder In $colFolder) {
  ```

  The loop variable `$strFolder` does not contain strings, but `DirectoryInfo` objects. This is a prime example for why I consider hungarian notation a pointless waste of space.
- Avoid unnecessary steps.

  ```
  $Path = $strFolder.FullName
  $Folder = Get-Item $Path
  ```

  `$strFolder` already contains a `DirectoryInfo` object. The above two statements just convert it to a path string and back to a `DirectoryInfo` object. Simply make `$Folder` your loop variable (see above).
- Avoid duplicate code (particularly duplicate disk operations):

  ```
  $strOldestTime = (Get-ChildItem $Path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1).LastWriteTime
  $strNewestTime = (Get-ChildItem $Path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last  1).LastWriteTime
  ```

  Instead of listing and sorting the child items multiple times run the statement just once and collect the result in a variable:

  ```
  $items = Get-ChildItem $Path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
  $strOldestTime = ($items | Select-Object -First 1).LastWriteTime
  $strNewestTime = ($items | Select-Object -Last 1).LastWriteTime
  ```

  Also, I would simply expand the `LastWriteTime` property instead of running `Select-Object` in a subexpression:

  ```
  $strOldestTime = $items | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand LastWriteTime
  $strNewestTime = $items | Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime
  ```
- Misused hungarian notation (pt.2):
  `$strOldestTime` and `$strNewestTime` contain `DateTime` objects, not strings.
- `$foldername = $Folder.Name.split("\")[-1]`:
  The `Name` property already contains the folder name without path, so there's nothing to split off.
- Construct the new folder name from the date and the current name by using the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx):

  ```
  $newname = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1}' -f $oldestTime, $Folder.Name
  ```
- If there's a possibility that you'll run the script multiple times you may want to remove an existing leading date from the folder name so that the dates won't "stack":

  ```
  $Folder.Name -replace '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} - '
  ```

Simplified code:

```
$colFolder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
             Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
             Sort-Object Fullname -Descending

foreach ($folder in $colFolder) {
  $items = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | Sort-Object LastWriteTime

  $folder.CreationTime  = $items | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand LastWriteTime
  $folder.LastWriteTime = $items | Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime

  $newname = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1}' -f $folder.CreationTime, ($folder.Name -replace '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} - ')

  Rename-Item -Path $folder.FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

or (PowerShell v3 and newer):

```
$colFolder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |
             Sort-Object Fullname -Descending

foreach ($folder in $colFolder) {
  $items = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | Sort-Object LastWriteTime

  $folder.CreationTime  = $items | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand LastWriteTime
  $folder.LastWriteTime = $items | Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime

  $newname = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1}' -f $folder.CreationTime, ($folder.Name -replace '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} - ')

  Rename-Item -LiteralPath $folder.FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and very good comments. I wish someone could give suggestions like that for Java, C++, Python code I write. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @wmac [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place if you're looking for that kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Rename-Item oldname newname
```

It works for simple examples, but could break with folders nested in other folders, and recursion, because you might rename a folder before the script is done with it.

To manage that you can do them in order by length (paths to children being by definition longer than the paths of the parents). Good example here: [How do I recursively rename folders with Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216373/how-do-i-recursively-rename-folders-with-powershell?rq=1)

Comment: also, if the file name contains strange characters, you might have to use move-item -literalpath

Comment: Starting with PowerShell v3 `Rename-Item` has a parameter `-LiteralPath` too.